# Supertest: Received stream is empty even though it works in the browser and with curl

Tags: node.js, http, stream, supertest

Today, I have tried to create an end-to-end test for an endpoint which triggers a download using `stream.pipe(res)`. This works just fine using the browser and curl.

I have created the following minimal reproducible example:

Test code:

```js
it('minimal example for testing download endpoints', async () => {
  const r = await request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/reporter/test');
  // This should pipe 'THIS IS SOME TEST DATA STREAMED INTO THE RESPONSE' into test.txt but it is empty :(
  r.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.txt'));
});
```

Server:

```js
@Get('test-endpoint')
async testDownload(@Res() res: Response) {
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=test.txt`);
  return Readable.from(
    'THIS IS SOME TEST DATA STREAMED INTO THE RESPONSE'
  ).pipe(res);
}
```

As I understand it, the file 'test.txt' should contain the string 'THIS IS SOME TEST DATA STREAMED INTO THE RESPONSE' as shown in the browser or on the terminal using curl.

But the file is empty.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with supertest? If I understand the [documentation](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#piping-data) correctly , this should work.

I am using supertest 4.0.2 with superagent 3.8.3, node 15.0.1 and @nestjs/common v7.0.9 and @nestjs/core 7.0.9

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about using a non-experimental version of Node like 14 or 12?

Comment: Switched to node 14.0.0 with nvm but still same issue :( File is empty in test but browser downloads it correctly

Comment: Probably `await` is not necessary if you want to use it as a stream.

Comment: The document says "It's not possible to mix pipes and callbacks or promises." The `await` is using the `r` as a promise. I get an error "Error: end() has already been called, so it's too late to start piping" with `await`, but it works without `await` for me.

Comment: Oh my god, you are my savior! This does indeed work without `await`!

I should learn to read documentation thoroughly.
Can I mark your comment as the correct answer?